# Past exam paper finding eigenspaces from eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra

Q:Suppose $ϕ : \mathbb{R}_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_2$ has the following matrix with respect to the standard basis:

$$\pmatrix{0&-1\\2&3}$$

Find the eigenvalues and the eigenspaces of $ϕ$.

> A:This question was covered by my professor in a revision lecture, however he admitted that the answer he gave was incorrect.
>
> After working at the problem I have found the eigenvalues to be $1, 2$ both of linear multiplicity

How would one go about finding the eigenspace?

> Is the answer my professor gave:
>
> "the basis of $U_1$ is $\left\lbrace \pmatrix{1\\1} \right\rbrace$"
>
> "the basis of $U_2 is \left\lbrace \pmatrix{-1/2\\1} \right\rbrace$"
>
> anywhere near the true value?

Finally is the eigenspace the collection of both basis together, are they two separate eigenspaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic function is $p(t) = t(t-3) + 2= (t-2)(t-1)$, so the eigenvalues are $1$ and $2$. Since the matrix is $2 \times 2$, each eigenvalue must have multiplicity $1$.

To find the $\lambda$-eigenspace, just find the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$ where $A$ is your matrix. For instance, with $\lambda=1$, you want the nullspace of $\begin{bmatrix}-1&-1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}$, which is spanned by $(1,-1)$. Similarly, for $\lambda=2$ you want the nullspace of $\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$ which is spanned by $(-1/2,1)$.

Comment: How do find the null space and how do you find the vector it is spanned by. Correct me, from my notes, the to find the null space you do row operations, identify the columns with leading ones. The spanning vector is when $A*u=0$.